# Selenium is normal during debugging, but the run click fails

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I've searched several solutions but it didn't work.
That's my code

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://baijia.baidu.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'getMoreArticles'))).click()
content = driver.page_source
page = open('test.html','wb')
page.write(content)
```

I've tried to debug the code, It successfully returns the clicked page.
when I run the code, it also returns successfully, however it don't returns the clicked page, just the source page.

I tried to search the solutions, take the page down to the bottom:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)",element)
```

But it's the same result, only debug successfully.

Thanks

Comment: does that open a new tab?

Comment: @NimishBansal no, that click button is just to load more. Debugging will succeed and the run will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your button initiate an AJAX request. Driver doesn't wait it finished, because there is no page reload. So you should add explicit wait. Something like that:

```
expected_number_of_articles = 10 # enter your number
article_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#article') # enter your locator
wait.until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements(*article_locator)) >= expected_number_of_articles)
```

Comment: Oh, i saw the `Request Headers` in Chrome , it seems really an Ajax request, but i don't understand the meaning of `expected_number_of_articles` in your code . Thanks!

Comment: for example, you have 10 articles on a page. So you click "getMoreArticles" to load more 10. Then `expected_number_of_articles = 20`

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing page source wait for a small interval to wait for page load

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://baijia.baidu.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'getMoreArticles'))).click()
time.sleep(4)
content = driver.page_source
page = open('test3.html','w')
page.write(content)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.But if i want to click it more than one time. likes this:  
`for i in range(5):  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)  
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'getMoreArticles'))).click()`
The same will be returned for the third and fourth time, or the twice and the third, anyway, there is a problem. Besides, i don't want to use `time.sleep()`,  it is unstable, and slow.

Comment: can you tell approximately how many characters will be there in your desired output?

Comment: i didn't get you.Are you sayng you have to tap the button 15 times?